# ltrace exit with "is not an ELF file" for an executable that file finds "ELF 32-bit LSB shared object" on armv7

Tags: arm, ltrace

I am working on a armv7-a and try to use ltrace installed via buildroot.

```
# ltrace /usr/bin/ssh-keygen -t ecdsa -b 256
"/usr/bin/ssh-keygen" is not an ELF file

# file /usr/bin/ssh-keygen
/usr/bin/ssh-keygen: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.16, stripped
```

Upstream [supports](https://github.com/s-macke/ltrace) armv7, but says:

> The following targets are currently (at least somewhat) supported.
>   Some of them may be more or less broken in reality

Has one made it work please?

Comment: You're running `ltrace` on `ssh-keygen` but `file` on `ssh`. Which one is it?

Comment: you are right, sorry. But it is the same result. I have edited the OP.